# Appengine Java MapReduce : Save all results in one google cloud file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, mapreduce

I wan't to do a database export jobs in CSV, I think to use a Mapreduce Job, read all datastore entity with the DatastoreInput, in the mapper, juste emit the CSV string for the current entity, and use the ValueProjectionReducer to just pass through values.
But the CloudSqlFileOutput write one file for each shards jobs.
How to export all csv lines in one file with the mapreduce library ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the number of reducers to 1. (In versions up to 0.5 this is done one the output class.)